# VBA to set autofilter in a differnt workbook to Select All for all columns

Tags: excel, filter, excel-2007, vba

I extract data from a report into Excel, then I use this code to verify if another workbook is open (for this example it would be "Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm"). If the target workbook is open, then the sub will copy the valid data to the target workbook. The target workbook has the Filter turned on for columns A:AE. What I need to do is have the sub change all the filters to "Select All" so that there are no hidden rows before copying the valid data to it. I have looked this up in SO, but I could not find anything that matches what I am looking for. I also recorded a macro to see if that will work, but it did not. Not sure how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub Extract_Sort_1601_January()

Dim ANS As Long

ANS = MsgBox("Is the January 2016 Swivel Master File checked out of SharePoint and currently open on this desktop?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbDefaultButton1, "Master File Open")
If ANS = vbNo Or IsWBOpen("Swivel - Master - January 2016") = False Then
    MsgBox "The required workbook is not currently open. This procedure will now terminate.", vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Terminate Procedure"
    Exit Sub
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' This line autofits the columns C, D, O, and P
    Range("C:C,D:D,O:O,P:P").Columns.AutoFit

    ' This unhides any hidden rows
    Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False

Dim LR As Long

    For LR = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("B" & LR).Value <> "1" Then
            Rows(LR).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next LR

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Extract").Sort
    With .SortFields
        .Clear
        .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("O2:O2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("J2:J2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("K2:K2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Add Key:=Range("L2:L2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    End With
    .SetRange Range("A2:AE2000")
    .Apply
End With
Cells.WrapText = False
Sheets("Extract").Range("A2").Select

    Dim LastRow As Integer, i As Integer, erow As Integer

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Cells(i, 2) = "1" Then

            ' As opposed to selecting the cells, this will copy them directly
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 31)).Copy

            ' As opposed to "Activating" the workbook, and selecting the sheet, this will paste the cells directly
            With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
                erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                .Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            End With
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this code right before your loop to copy / paste (I think).

```
With Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel")
    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    .Range("A1:AE" & erow).AutoFilter 'leaving arguments blank clears all filters, but leaves the drop-down arrows (filter mode still on)
End With
```

Or if leaving FilterMode on is not an issue (meaning if leaving it in a state where no filtering arrows appear) just do this:

```
Workbooks("Swivel - Master - January 2016.xlsm").Sheets("Swivel").AutoFilterMode = False
```

Comment: I added all the code in your first part (With to End With) just above the With/End With of my code that performs the Paste. I received a RT 1004 "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed and '.Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll' was highlighted by the debugger. Did I do something wrong? Also, I do need to keep the filters on, just cleared out.

Comment: paste the `With` block in my code just above the line in your code just above `LastRow = ...`. You only need to clear the filter once. Not each time you loop.

Comment: Thank you. That was another duh moment for me today. This worked exactly as I needed it to.

Comment: I got a little too anxious to answer I think. I just noticed that the Filter is now turned off on all my columns. I used your With/End With block.

Comment: When you say turned off? What do you mean? Are there arrows there? Or do you want the data to be filtered the way you had it before running the code?

Comment: Sorry, by turned off I mean the arrows are not there. I think the best way to say it is that the code should unfilter the data (return to normal state) but leave the filter available. Does that make sense?

Comment: the line `.Range("A1:AE" & erow).AutoFilter` will do just what you want. Are you sure you didn't use `AutoFilterMode = False` anywhere?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I have. I do not have 'AutoFilterMode = False' anywhere in the sub.

Comment: okay. it did not behave as I expected. Add the same `With block` just outside the `For` loop, after the `Next` statement.

Comment: That worked. Thanks for all your help on this Scott. Much appreciated.